# Написать простой http-прокси-сервер который изменяет контент на странице перед выдачей

Tags: python, сокет, proxy, задание-на-собеседовании

Решил сделать небольшое задание с собеседований, задание вкратце следующее:

Необходимо написать простой http-прокси-сервер, запускаемый локально, который показывает содержимое страниц Хабра (https://habr.com/ru/all/).
Всем словам с длиной от 6 символов добавить ™. При этом страница, открытая с помощью локального адреса, должна визуально полностью соответствовать странице на habr'e за исключением измененного текста.
Удалось написать простой прокси сервер, изменить слова в посте. Но потерялись некоторые элементы сайта: истории, читают сейчас и т.п.
[image: Страница открытая через мой прокси сервер]

[image: Страница оригинальная]

Прикладываю свой код:

```
import http.server
import http.client
import socketserver
import bs4
import re
import time

DELAY = 0.001

class ProxyHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        target_host = 'habr.com'
        print('-'*37)

        client = http.client.HTTPSConnection(target_host)
        client.request('GET', self.path)
        response = client.getresponse()

        # Получаю страницу в строковом представлении
        html = response.read().decode('utf-8')  
        # Модифицирую текст поста  
        modifed_html = self.modife_html(html)
        
        time.sleep(DELAY)
        
        # Отправляю status code
        self.send_response(response.status)
        # Добавляю заголовки
        for header in response.getheaders():
            self.send_header(*header)
        
        self.end_headers()
        # self.copyfile(response, self.wfile)
        self.wfile.write(modifed_html)

        client.close()

    @staticmethod
    def modife_html(html):
        """
        Метод модифицирует текст страницы
        """
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

        try:
            # Получаю все теги <p> поста
            ps = soup.find('div', {'id':'post-content-body'}).find_all('p')

            pattern = r"(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))[a-zA-ZА-Яа-я-]{6,}(?=\s|\,|\.|\:)"

            for p in ps:
                # print('-'*20)
                # print(p.get_text())
            
                text = str(p.get_text())
                out = re.sub(pattern, r'\g<0>™', text)
                p.replace_with(out)

        except Exception as ex:
            print('На странице не найдено поста')
            print('Exception', ex)

        # Возвращаю страницу
        return soup.prettify().encode('utf-8')


def run_proxy_server():
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 8080

    with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), ProxyHandler) as httpd:
        print('server is running at', HOST + ':' + str(PORT))
        httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_proxy_server()
```

Вопрос: возможно ли как-то доработать данный код, чтобы корректно отображать страницу после внесения в нее правок? Прошу подсказать в какую сторону стоит копать информацию, какие инструменты использовать

Comment: Открой инспектор и посмотри какие скрипты не загрузились